# Not able to get the expected date output after adding a second

Tags: shell

What I'm trying to do below

```
echo -e "input start_time(YYYYMMDDHHMMSS)"    
read word1    
dt= `date "--date=${word1} -s + 1sec" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`    
echo ${dt}
```

If input : `20181201090909` then I got an output : `20181201090909030001`. The expected output is quite incorrect. I was expecting it to be `20181201090910`

Comment: It seems you are doing a string concatenation instead of a number adding. Can you try using `expr` or `bc`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to format differently the string you pass to date:

> ~$ date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S --date="20181201 09:09:09  + 1sec"
>   20181201090910
>   ~$

You see a space between the date and the time, and the colon separating hour minutes seconds. See `info date` for more information.